# How to append data in a file by dd?

Tags: unix, ssd, dd

I want to append new data in a file stored in SSD.

```
dd if=/dev/shm/test of=/data/sdb/test bs=1G oflag=append
```

But df -h shows the dd command always overwrite the test file, instead appends new data in the test file. 
I also tried

```
dd if=/dev/shm/test of=/data/sdb/test bs=1G conv=notrunc
```

It does not work, either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about:

```
 dd if=/dev/shm/test bs=1G >>/data/sdb/test
```

Comment: your solution works. Thanks. But do you know why my solutions don't work? I have checked the man page. cannot find the reason. thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to add `count=`: `... bs=1G count=1 >> ...`

Answer (score 48):

```
dd if=/dev/shm/test of=/data/sdb/test bs=1G oflag=append conv=notrunc
```

That is what I think you should have used.

REF : https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=373736

Comment: Without `count=1` option it appends all available space.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way to append a sparse hole to a file.

> `truncate` is much faster than dd. To grow the file with 10 bytes use:
>
> ```
>  truncate -s +10 file.txt
> ```

answer found in:
https://serverfault.com/a/343726/70242

Answer (score 1):

In Linux kernel 4.1 `FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE` option was added. From `fallocate(2)` [man page](http://manpages.org/fallocate/2):

> Specifying the FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE flag (available since Linux 4.1)
>   in mode increases the file space by inserting a hole within the file
>   size without overwriting any existing data. The hole will start at
>   offset and continue for len bytes. When inserting the hole inside
>   file, the contents of the file starting at offset will be shifted
>   upward (i.e., to a higher file offset) by len bytes. Inserting a hole
>   inside a file increases the file size by len bytes.

And recently this option support [was added](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/b439065634e693dda385a6e5269e1d9258d6d471) to `util-linux`:

> ```
>    -i, --insert-range
>           Insert a hole of length bytes from offset, shifting existing
>           data.
> ```

So when `util-linux` version 2.30 will be released and your linux distro will update to this version we will be able to increase file size in a flash by running:

```
fallocate -i -l 1G -o 128M /path/to/file
```

where `128M` is the current file size.