# Split binary file at offset quickly

Tags: macos, unix, splitter, binary-files

The file I need to split is 32GB.

I need to split the file into two parts at an offset I specify and I only need to keep the second part.

I can do this easily by:

```
dd if=binary_file.bin of=second_part.bin bs=1 skip=143254
```

However, this is taking a *very long* time time (hours) to complete and I need a command line method that will complete the process much faster.

Any suggestions?

I am using OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan).

Comment: Do you really need `bs=1`? That means it is reading byte for byte which will be extremely slow.

Comment: Yes, I know it is really, really, really slow. If I need to use the offset of 143253, then what would you suggest?

Comment: Whatever the answer. Bs=1 for the whole file will always be needlessly slow. It is like copying a book letter for letter. As in read one letter, write one letter. Normally you would read one sentence and then copy that. So that is what we want to do for to biggest part of the file. Now we just need to figure out how to get around the weird offset.

Answer (score 1):

I came here seeking the same thing, and on further research, found out several things:

###### 1. dd (coreutils) has flags to specify different units for `bs`, `skip` and `count`. Where `skip` and `count` must either be in bytes or match the `bs` value.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1178771)

This is done by using `iflag` argument, and `skip_bytes` and/or `count_bytes`.
In your case, like this:

```bash
dd if=binary_file.bin of=second_part.bin bs=4M skip=143254 iflag=skip_bytes
```

###### 2. If using coreutils `dd` isn't an option for MacOS users, you could also use two different `dd` commands and pipe them.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28859713)

Something like this:

```bash
dd if=binary_file.bin bs=143254 skip=1 | dd bs=4M count=1 > second_part.bin
```

or better yet skip the second `dd` and pipe the output to a file directly:

```bash
dd if=binary_file.bin bs=143254 skip=1 > second_part.bin
```

But all this has been tested by me on smaller files and may be heavy on your memory depending on the file size.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe read a few bytes up to a 4k boundary and then a second command to append the rest?

Assuming we want to end on a 4K boundary (most filesystems seem to use 4K internal buffers).

1. Skip up to part where you want to start reading. (bs=1 skip=143254)
2. read from 143254 till 143254 with bs=1 and count=3990
3. Read the rest of the file with bs=4k and append it to the output file. ( See [how to append data in a file by dd](https://superuser.com/questions/850267/how-to-append-data-in-a-file-by-dd) here on SU)

If that is too slow and you are scripting this as a repetative task you could even optimise further by doing 512b reads for the first 3584 bytes (7*512), then 400-ish single byte reads and the rest at 4k size.

<sup>Note that this answer feels as a workaround. I will enjoy reading the other answers which this question will attract. Maybe even a clean solution which just seeks to 143254 and then uses normal read/write opteration to copy, allowing filesystem defaults to be used rather than my explicit assumptions about 4k internal buffers.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about OS X, but I assume this should work:

```
filesize=$(wc -c <"binary_file.bin")

tail -c $(($filesize-143254)) binary_file.bin > second_part.bin
```

alternatively you could do (the +1 is needed, because of in my opinion strange interpration of tail of this value):

```
tail -c +$((143254+1)) binary_file.bin > second_part.bin
```